# Adding a rewrite rule to my existing rules in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My current htaccess file is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

I want to add another rule that redirects www.example.com to http://example.com with a 301 Redirect. I know the rule I need to add is

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But where do I add this? Do I append this to the end of my current file, or do all Conditions go together, and then all rules together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can append , **[L]** represent the last rule , so first make it your last rule after use redirect **[L,R=301]**

Use following code in your case

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```